# High GPU RAM and power usage after nvidia-drivers update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, gpu

I updated my nvidia-drivers from 430.1 to 440.44 to install the latest cuda software 10.1 (which suggested that I need to update my nvidia drivers to 440). After the update, it seems that there is high GPU RAM usage in idle itself.

```
Wed Jan 15 22:22:43 2020
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44       Driver Version: 440.44       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P0    30W / 120W |   1117MiB /  6075MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+    
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory | 
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1996      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           109MiB |
|    0      2658      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        1004MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When 430.1 version was installed, the gpu usage at idle never rose above 300MB. At idle, these two same processes were running but the total GPU memory usage was less than 300MB. Power consumption in 430.1 always stayed below 10W at idle and rose only after I ran some GPU heavy applications. After installing 440.44, the GPU RAM usage is insanely high, at 1117MB, which is a lot. Also the power consumption is at a high 30W at idle, it does drop if I don't use the computer at all. But if I open an application like Firefox, it bumps up to 30W and then after a few minutes, it goes back to 10W.
What is the reason behind the high GPU RAM usage of gnome-shell especially, almost 1GB at idle? Is it a driver-issue?

Graphics-card details ---

```
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@60.02hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.44
```

edit: reformatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed drivers from nvidia driver version 440 to 430 which seemed to have solved the RAM issue and power management. Reinstalled 440, and it now does not have the problems as stated in the question. Guess the way to fix it was to reinstall it.